# SSIS APPEND Data to table

Tags: ssis, append

I have a SSIS package v.2010. 
Process:
Truncates destination table
Data Flow --> Source DB and dumps table into destination db

What I would like to do, is only Append new records into the destination table. How would one go about doing this? I tried removing my truncate statement but this adds duplicate values.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "incremental load" You haven't specified whether the source data can change and therefore you need to identify both new + changed records but there are plenty of answers here to help you

Comment: Yes, that term is helpful "incremental load" , thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to create a staging table that the data flow fills and then use a SQL task to run a merge statement to merge the staging table into the destination.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to a merge statement is to use a Lookup transformation in the data flow to see which rows you already have in the destination table (if there is a way you can identify a row). Then use the 'not matched' flow from the lookup to do your inserts.

It also helps if you can identify which rows are 'new since the last time you ran successfully' in the source db. For this you'd need some kind of date/time column or rowversion in the source db, and you could record where you got to in the SSIS package by writing to a separate table.